Search results in 284 records but deleting these records ends up with over 2000 records
Drupal 9, civiCRM 5.72.3
Someone starting using my site to test credit card validity, over-riding CAPTCHA, Form Protection, etc. Each attempt opens a new record in the db and I want to delete these. Using Advanced Search, I search for Activity Type=Failed Payment and get 284 records but when I select to delete these records (or put them is a separate group) civi wants to delete over 2000 records. Some of these may be "Failed Payments" from the past but others have no payment activity whatsoever.
Any idea what is causing this behavior?

Could it be that you have 284 as the count of Contacts who have between them made over 2000 contributions.
When you do an Adv Search, by default it gives a count of Contacts.
If you use Find Contributions, it gives a count of Contributions.
In Adv Search - at the top left, you have an option to change between 'show results as' Contacts or Contributions or Activities - so flipping between those settings might confirm the above.
